# Avconv streaming to URL - need help

Tags: streaming-video, node.js, ffmpeg, picamera

I'm trying to learn as I go but haven't managed to come up with the answer to my issue here. I'm trying to stream to a URL using the 'pi-camera-connect' package and the 'avconv' package.

The video on the URL is just black and no sound.

I've never really dealt with streams before, so I imagine I'm doing all sorts wrong. Would appreciate the help.

```
const { StreamCamera, Codec } = require("pi-camera-connect");
var avconv = require('avconv');

const streamCamera = new StreamCamera({
    codec: Codec.H264
});

const runApp = async () => {

    const videoStream = streamCamera.createStream();
    await streamCamera.startCapture();

    var URL = "HIDDEN_URL";

    var params = [
        '-i', 'pipe:0', // Tell avconv to expect an input stream (via its stdin)
        '-f', 'flv',  
        '-strict', 'experimental',
        URL
    ];

    var process = avconv(params);

    process.on('error', function(data) {
        console.log("Stream Error", data.toString());
    });

    process.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Stream data", data.toString());
    });

    process.once('exit', function(exitCode, signal, metadata) {
        console.log("Stream Exit", exitCode.toString());
    });

    process.on('progress', function(progress) {
        console.log("Stream progress", progress.toString());
    });

    videoStream.pipe(process);

}

runApp();
```

It does generate the 'The driver for the TC358743 HDMI to CSI2 chip you are using is NOT supported' error but I understand that's always written out. Nothing else ends up in the console log.

I have been able to use the 'pi-camera' node package and write a new video file but I don't know how to use pi-camera to create a stream to send to the avconv process.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Looks like I needed to add the -vcodec parameter.

```
var params = [
    '-i', 'pipe:0', // Tell avconv to expect an input stream (via its stdin)
    '-f', 'flv',  
    '-vcodec', 'copy',
    '-strict', 'experimental',
    URL
];
```